# matlab matrices and fold list

Tags: matlab, matrix, wolfram-mathematica

i have two problems in mathematica and want to do them in matlab:

```
measure := RandomReal[] - 0.5
m = 10000;
data = Table[measure, {m}];
fig1 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.015]}]
Histogram[data]
```

matlab:

```
measure =@ (m) rand(1,m)-0.5
m=10000;
for i=1:m
data(:,i)=measure(:,i);
end

figure(1)
plot(data,'b.','MarkerSize',0.015)

figure(2)
hist(data)
```

And it gives me :

> ??? The following error occurred
>   converting from function_handle to
>   double: Error using ==> double

If i do :

```
measure =rand()-0.5
    m=10000;
data=rand(1,m)-0.5
```

then, i get the right results in plot1 but in plot 2 the y=axis is wrong.

Also, if i have this in mathematica :

```
steps[m_] := Table[2 RandomInteger[] - 1, {m}]
steps[20] 
Walk1D[n_] :=  FoldList[Plus, 0, steps[n]]
LastPoint1D[n_] := Fold[Plus, 0, steps[n]]
ListPlot[Walk1D[10^4]]
```

I did this :

```
steps = @ (m) 2*randint(1,m,2)-1;
steps(20)

Walk1D =@ (n) cumsum(0:steps(n))  --> this is ok i think
LastPointold1D= @ (n) cumsum(0:steps(n))
LastPoint1D= @ (n) LastPointold1D(end)-->but here i now i must take the last "folding"
Walk1D(10)
LastPoint1D(10000)
plot(Walk1D(10000),'b')
```

and i get an empty matrix and no plot..

Comment: Please describe what you actually want to do.

Comment: I want the above to work,but as i say they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @Itamar essentially answered your first question, here is a comment on the second one. You did it almost right. You need to define

```
Walk1D = @ (n) cumsum(steps(n));
```

since `cumsum` is a direct analog of `FoldList[Plus,0,your-list]`. Then, the `plot` in your code works fine. Also, notice that, either in your Mathematica or Matlab code, it is not necessary to define `LastPoint1D` separately - in both cases, it is the last point of your generated list (vector) `steps`.

EDIT:

Expanding a bit on `LastPoint1D`: my guess is that you want it to be a last point of the walk computed by `Walk1D`. Therefore, it would IMO make sense to just make it a function of a generated walk (vector), that returns its last point. For example:

```
lastPoint1D = @(walk) (walk(end));
```

Then, you use it as:

```
walk = Walk1D(10000);
lastPoint1D(walk)
```

HTH

Comment: Hello,it worked now,but the result of LastPoint1D(10000) is always "1" or "-1" when i run the program.In mathematica when i evaluate the nb it takes different numbers every time in a wide range.

Comment: Ok ,it works fine now!But i can't understand why if i do :LastPoint1D(10000)  doesn't do the same as :walk=Walk1D(10000);LastPoint1D(walk).Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors/mistakes translating your code to Matlab:

- If I am not wrong, the line `data = Table[measure, {m}];` creates `m` copies of `measure`, which in your case will create a random vector of size (1,m). If that is true, in Matlab it would simply be `data = measure(m);`
- The function you define gets a single argument `m`, therefor it makes no sense using a matrix notation (the `:`) when calling it.
- Just as a side-note, if you insert data into a matrix inside a `for` loop, it will run much faster if you allocate the matrix in advance, otherwise Matlab will re-allocate memory to resize the matrix in each iteration. You do this by `data = zeros(1,m);`.
- What do you mean by "in plot 2 the y=axis is wrong"? What do you expect it to be?

**EDIT**

Regarding your 2nd question, it would be easier to help you if you describe in words what you want to achieve, rather than trying to read your (error producing) code. One thing which is clearly wrong is using expression like `0:steps(n)`, since you use `m:n` with two scalars `m` and `n` to produce a vector, but `steps(n)` produces a vector, not a scalar. You probably get an empty matrix since the first value in the vector returned by `steps(n)` might be -1, and `0:-1` produces an empty vector.

Comment: Hello.The data=measure(m) worked fine but still the problem with plot2.I mean that the bars i am taking from plot have a height of about 1000.But in mathematica have a height at about 500.Also,if you could tell me what can i do with the second problem..Thanks a lot!

Comment: The height of the bars depend on the "bin width" you define, and the default value is probably different from Mathematica to Matlab. You can use `hist(x, n)` or `hist(x, binVals)` in Matlab in order to specify number of bins or bin centers. Regarding the 2nd question, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok with this,i used hist(data,20).

Comment: I want to emulate the foldlist command.For example," FoldList[Plus, 0, Range[9]]" gives "{0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45}" and "Fold[Plus, 0, Range[9]]" gives "45".With cumsum(0:steps(n)) i create a vector which is what i want.But the problem is when i must take the last element as is needed by LastPoint1D above.